# phpmyadmin 404 error in nginx

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I've installed phpmyadmin via `ppa` in my Ubuntu machine ,but when try to access localhost/phpmyadmin i got 404 error

server is nginx

```
location /phpmyadmin{
            index index.php;
            root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
          }   
     location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
         #fastcgi_index index.php;
         include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Found so many questions related to this issue but nothing solved my problem

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log?

Answer (score 4):

The symlink created in that guide points to `/usr/share/nginx/www` while your `root` directive points to another directory. Unless you specify another location block, NGINX doesn't technically know that the directory exists, and doesn't know where to route the incoming request.

First, remove the symlink you just created by running:

```
rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/www
```

That won't delete phpMyAdmin, it'll just delete the symlink. Now we'll create a new one using:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Since you've set `root` to `/var/www/html`, that's your "home" directory or `root` path that your server block uses. What the above command does is create a symlink from where the phpMyAdmin files are to your root directory.

Once the new symlink is there, you should be able confirm that by running:

```
ls -al /var/www/html
```

That should produce something that looks like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr  4 14:31 phpmyadmin -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

Which means the symlink is valid and should now work when you visit:

```
http://IP_ADDR/phpmyadmin
```

Where IP_ADDR is your IP address.

Comment: Shouldn't the `root` directive in the configuration file handle that without needing a symlink at all?

Comment: I don't see that guide anymore, but I can't think of scenario where this is necessary. @savaliya for such tasks there are the `root` and `alias` directives.

Comment: use this link help you  :- (https://askubuntu.com/questions/306094/phpmyadmin-throws-a-404-on-opening/306130)

Comment: @savaliya the link leads to solution for apache2 not nginx. Further on the target page the why he is using links is as the apache2 instance is not finding his configuration file and not the document root.

Comment: I used sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ phpmyadmin from within /var/www/html and it worked  ls -la | grep "\->" is one way to just check the folder for symbolic links  (Ubuntu 17.04 server nginx 1.10.3)

Answer (score 0):

Your `root` is not correctly configured.

`root` sets the path BEFORE adding the location.

```
<root> + <location>

location /phpmyadmin{
        index index.php;
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
      }
```

This leads to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/`

What you want is:

```
location /phpmyadmin{
        index index.php;
        root /usr/share/;
      }
```