# I recieve a file instead of access PhpMyAdmin page

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

When I installed Php, PhpMyAdmin and Nginx, I recievied this file with these code file instead of access to

http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;

if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}

global $route, $containerBuilder;

require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';

$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

I've done like this
[phpmyadmin 404 error in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470443/phpmyadmin-404-error-in-nginx)
to fix the 404 error but after that I've received error above.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You webserver is not correctly configured to execute pages with the `.php` extension as PHP.

Comment: I know that my webserver is not correctly configured. But as a newbie, I don't know how to fix that. I've tried to reinstall but it still gone wrong.

Comment: Have you tried [one of the many articles that can help you](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Nginx-PHP-FPM-config-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: you need to check status of nginx server with command line:

`sudo service nginx status`

- If nginx server not active,try to restart nginx server with command line `sudo service nginx restart`
- If you see failed, let's check what program is running on port 80 (let's me know in the comment). The common error is caused by the apache2 server running on port 80 (If this is true, go to the next step).

Step 2: The are two solution for you

1, Stop server apache2 with this commana line:

`sudo service apache2 stop`

Restart nginx server:

`sudo service nginx restart`

Check status nginx server again, it's should be ok right now.

2, Change port apache2
You need to change two file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

For example, I change port apache2 from 80 to 8888:

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf` and change `Listen 80` to `Listen 8888`

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf` and change `<VirtualHost: *:80>` to `<VirtualHost: *:8080>`

After that, restart the apache2 server and nginx server:

- Restart apache2 server: `sudo service apache2 restart`
- Restart nginx server: `sudo service nginx restart`

Please leave comment if anything you want to ask.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your advice but I can't see what program using port 80 huykhoi@huykhoi-Vostro-3480:~$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  594 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  24071      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
cupsd      869            root    6u  IPv6  27965      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      869            root    7u  IPv4  27966      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1016           mysql   21u  IPv4  24386      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1016           mysql   23u  IPv4  29096      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)

Comment: Can you give me link image of command line 'sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN' in this comment, it would be great

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the proper package for php for nginx

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-fpm -y
```

You need also to have a proper nginx configuration file (here for localhost)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```